# Removing GlobeBrowserBalloon controls

Tags: worldwind

I am trying to remove the forward and back buttons from my GlobeBrowserBalloons, as I only want to keep the closing X.

I know that the method is `balloon.removeBrowserControl(AbstractBrowserBalloon.BrowserControl browserControl);`
And the constructor arguments for BrowserControl are `(String action, Offset offset, Object imageSource)`

My question is, what do I put in the constructor for the BrowserControl? I am not familiar with what action and imageSource are.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the directional browser controls from a `GlobeBrowserBalloon` this way:

```
Iterable<AbstractBrowserBalloon.BrowserControl> bc = balloon.getBrowserControls();
        Iterator<AbstractBrowserBalloon.BrowserControl> br = bc.iterator();
        while (br.hasNext()) {
            if (!(br.next().getAction().equals("gov.nasa.worldwind.avkey.Close"))){
                br.remove();
            }
        }
```

The actions are `Back`, `Forward`, and `Close`. The `imageSource` can be a string locating an image file.